# How to trim in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table like this: (can't change this)

```
id  value   other
-----------------------------
1   000033  sasdsa
2   000033  dasfgds
3   33      sadasdas
4   33      pdfsfsd
5   234543  posjfd
```

Can someone tell me how can I trim leading zeros with Linq?

I tryed this:

```
from t in table
where  (t.value.TrimStart('0')).Equals("33")
select t
```

but it doesn't work :S

Comment: Does it not work because you get an unsupported method exception, or the actual code doesn't produce the results you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'value' field is obviously a string since it's retained the leading zeroes. I've not tried but can you not cast the value as an integer before doing the comparison? Something like:

```
from t in table
where (t => Convert.ToInt32(t) == 33)
select t
```

If you need to keep the value as a string, you could use string.EndsWith() but you might have problems with matching the correct 'value'.